# How to run a new Random nextInt everytime you do something in java?

Tags: java, random, game-engine

So I am making a game (http://www.sharkinggame.tk) and I have to make a new Random Number each time I do such a thing, like, cast a fishing pole to see how long you are going to wait. So this is what I have which I belive should work.

```
public int generateNewRandomNumber() {
    Random r = new Random();
    int nextInt = r.nextInt(10000);
    return nextInt;
}
```

I already tried just saying `return r.nextInt(10000);` which didnt work either.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Why isn't it working? How is it behaving? what are you expecting?

Comment: Normally you would create the `Random` once (store it in a field, say) and call `nextInt()` on the same instance repeatedly.

Comment: Are you asking how to generate non-repeating random numbers?

Comment: What do you mean "didn't work"?  That covers a multitude of problems.  Also, what `import` do you have for `Random`?  Is it `java.util.Random` or some other class?

Comment: @JBNizet I'm trying to generate a new number between 0 and 10000 everytime I do an action

Comment: OK. so answer the questions from David Wallace and Chris. Saying "it doesn't work" is like going to the doctor and telling him "I'm sick". That doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a random integer up to some constant, as in

```
doSomething(randomNumberUpToConstant());
```

The correct way to do that is

```
public class EnclosingClass{
    Random r = new Random();

    final int MAX_RANDOM_VALUE = 10000;

    public void myMethod(){
        doSomething(r.nextInt(MAX_RANDOM_VALUE));
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, I'll delete my comment now that you've corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `Random r = new Random();` once, statically.  Then use that `r` wherever you need it. Do **not** keep recreating new instances.

Think of the `Random` object as a well - you dig one well and keep going back to it for water, you don't dig a new well every time you want a drink.

Answer (score 0):

By not working, I assume you get an error. That would result if you didn't add `import java.util.Random;` to the beginning of your file. Also, note that it is better to create the `Random` once. Your code will become something like this:

```
import java.util.Random;
class SomeClass{
    Random r;
    public SomeClass(){
        r = new Random();
    }
    public int getRandomNumber(){
        return r.nextInt(10000); //numbers in the range [0,10000)
    }
}
```

However, it doesn't really make sense to make a class like that. I'd just recommend using an instance of `Random` where you need it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyClass{
    private final Random r = new Random();

    private static final int RANGE = 10000;

    public int generateNewRandomNumber(){
        r.nextInt(RANGE);
    }
}
```